# How to solve gitlab merge blocker on the command line with git?

Tags: git, gitlab

When working with gitlab, I might come to a point where I cannot merge changes from a branch into the main branch. The error message given is

```
Merge blocked: fast-forward merge is not possible. To merge this request, first rebase locally.
```

So, supposing the local branch is `dev2`, I do the following on the local checkout of the repo:

```
git pull
git checkout main
git pull
git checkout dev2

git rebase main
<resolve the conflicts>
git add <file>
git rebase --continue
```

but what then? What commands do I have to enter now in order to resolve the merge conflict on gitlab?

At this stage the `git status` command gives the output

```
On branch dev2
Your branch and 'origin/dev2' have diverged,
and have 2 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

And when I follow the "advice" and do a

```
git pull
```

I have a conflict again. So that is not the correct command.

Comment: It's the correct *start* (although I recommend that users not use `git pull`, but rather break this into two separate commands, `git fetch` and then either rebase or merge depending on which one they *intend*). However, you will (almost always) get conflicts when you do this, and you must follow through by *resolving* those conflicts. Git is a tool, not a solution.

Comment: Once you have resolved the conflicts, you will need to use `git push --force` to update your merge request. If you've resolved everything properly, the updated merge request won't have merge conflicts unless you lost a race with someone else who created *new* merge conflicts (in which case, you must either win the next race, or talk to your coworkers / colleagues about this so that you aren't always in a race).

Comment: Yes, `git push --force` seems to work. Thanks